# Bootstrap 4 Collapse, switch between content, do not close selected content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two content versions that should show based on the visitor's choice. I'll call it Choice1 and Choice2. Choice1 is shown by default. I use Bootstrap 4.5's Collapse component. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="Offer">
<p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Choice1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="Choice1">Choice 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Choice2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Choice2">Choice 2</button>
</p>
<div class="collapse.show multi-collapse" id="Choice1" data-parent="#Offer">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
<p>Column 1</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
<p>Column 2</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
<p>Column 3</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="Choice2" data-parent="#Offer">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm">
<p>Column 11</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
<p>Column 22</p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm">
<p>Column 33</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My problem is that pressing buttons opens and closes the choices, while I want the selected choice stay always opened. Continuously pressing the same choice should not do anything, but leave that choice opened. I understand that "data-toggle" option stating collapse makes open/close possible. If I remove it from the choice 1, choice 2 shows under it, it does not replace it.

How do I disable close on selected option?

Thanks

Comment: Try a bootstrap Accordion. This can solve your problem

Comment: No, Accordion cannot be used from a simple design standpoint. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up by using NAV TABS instead of COLLAPSE. NAV TABS completely served my needs.